# Как ограничить поворот камеры по горизонтальной плоскости?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
public float sensitivityX = 15F;
public float sensitivityY = 15F;

public float minimumY = -60F;
public float maximumY = 60F;

float rotationY = 0F;
float rotationX = 0F;

void Start()
{

    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

void Update()
{
    if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY)
    {
        rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
        rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, 0 , 60);

        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
    }
 
    else
    {
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);

        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
    }
}
```

**Все плавно и хорошо. По Y все ограничивается как надо, но по X поворачивает только вправо, если заменить ноль в аргументах Mathf.Clamp на отрицательное значение персонажа лихорадит и повернуться не получается. Как можно обойти данный конфуз?**

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался, убрал данный трансформ у вращения по X.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]